# How to merge two columns of two different datasets in R so that i have NA or 0 values for the fields that have not been matched

Tags: r, merge, data-manipulation

I have two data frames and each of them have 10s of thousands of rows. The first data set of 35004 x 2 looks like below :

```
supplierid   counter
20030          1
20030          2
  '            '
  '            '
```

and each supplier's id repeats for 12 times and the second one of 18217 x 5 looks something like this:

```
 supplierid             SupplierName disbdate_eom month cnt
1:      23489 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2017-07-31     7   1
2:      61094        XXXXX XXXXXXXXX   2017-08-31     8   2
3:     123249      XXXXXX XX XXXXXXX   2018-02-28     2   3
4:     20030        XXXXXX XXXXXXXXX   2018-04-30     4   2
5:     132303       XX XXXX XXXXXXXX   2018-06-30     6   1
6:      20030        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2017-11-30    11   2
```

`cnt` is the number of sourcing per month and month is the month in numbers like for july its 7 and august 8.

All the supplier ids in the second dataset are present in the first one
I need to merge the two data frames such that I get the result.  So that for the month in which sourcing value is present, the value is reflected as that of second data set and for others the value is NA or 0s in the below Format:

```
 supplierid month      SupplierName disbdate_eom month cnt
 1:      20002     1          X          --        0    0
 2:      20002     2          X          --        0    0
 3:      20002     3          X          --        0    0
 4:      20002     4          X          --        4    34
 5:      20002     5          X          --        0    0
 6:      20002     6          X          --        0    0
 7:      20002     7          X          --        7    51
 8:      20002     8          X          --        8    12
 9:      20002     9          X          --        9    4
10:      20002    10          X          --        0    0
11:      20002    11          X          --        0    0
12:      20002    12          X          --        12   11
13:      20105     1          Y          --        0    0
14:      20105     2          Y          --        0    0
15:      20105     3          Y          --        3    6
```

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would really help here...

if I understood right you could try:

```
Df1 <- data.frame(supplierid = rep(501:503, each = 3), 
                  counter    = rep(1:3, times = 3))

Df2 <- data.frame(supplierid = c(501, 501, 502, 503), 
                  month      = c(1, 3, 2, 3),
                  cnt        = c(12, 7, 16, 10),
                  name       = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

Df3 <- merge(Df1, Df2, 
             by.x = c("supplierid", "counter"),
             by.y = c("supplierid", "month"), 
             all = TRUE)
```